# NameError: uninitialized constant UsersControllerTest::FILL_IN

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently working on chapter 10, part 1 of Michael Hartls RoR Tutorial and as of the test as in 10.25 my test is always red. I have gone through all the material and the message and looked here and on the web - I still have no solution...

The first error message:

```
ERROR["test_should_not_allow_the_admin_attribute_to_be_edited_via_the_web", UsersControllerTest, 1.8564385510981083]
 test_should_not_allow_the_admin_attribute_to_be_edited_via_the_web#UsersControllerTest (1.86s)
NameError:         NameError: uninitialized constant UsersControllerTest::FILL_IN
            test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:64:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

This is the test:

```
test "should not allow the admin attribute to be edited via the web" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    assert_not @other_user.admin?
    patch :update, id: @other_user, user: { password:              FILL_IN,
                                            password_confirmation: FILL_IN,
                                            admin: FILL_IN }
    assert_not @other_user.FILL_IN.admin?
  end
```

I have no idea where the FILL_IN came from, because I there was a certain amount of weeks between the two files...

The second is:

```
FAIL["test_valid_signup_information", UsersLoginTest, 2.0111586400307715]
 test_valid_signup_information#UsersLoginTest (2.01s)
        expecting <"users/show"> but rendering with <["user_mailer/account_activation", "layouts/mailer", "static_pages/home", "layouts/_shim", "layouts/_header", "layouts/_footer", "layouts/application"]>
        test/integration/users_login_test.rb:48:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
```

And the test looks like this:

```
test "login with valid information followed by logout" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
    delete logout_path
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Simulate a user clicking logout in a second window.
    delete logout_path
    follow_redirect!
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path,      count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0
  end

  test "valid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
      post_via_redirect users_path, user: { name:  "Example User",
                                            email: "user@example.com",
                                            password:              "password",
                                            password_confirmation: "password" }
    end
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert is_logged_in?
  end
```

Please tell me what else I can give as input to solve this puzzle.

Ah, the user that tries to log in in the second test is:

```
  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end
```

Otherwise known as:

```
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  admin: true
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
```

I appreciate any hint... Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

In your test file, where it says `FILL_IN`, you have to fill in with your own data.

```
test "should not allow the admin attribute to be edited via the web" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    assert_not @other_user.admin?

    #  =======  HERE =======
    patch :update, id: @other_user, user: { password:              FILL_IN,
                                            password_confirmation: FILL_IN,
                                            admin: FILL_IN }

    #  =======  HERE AS WELL =======
    assert_not @other_user.FILL_IN.admin?
  end
```

I guess you need to fill out those placeholders like so:

```
test "should not allow the admin attribute to be edited via the web" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    assert_not @other_user.admin?

    #  =======  HERE =======
    patch :update, id: @other_user, user: { password:              "user's password",
                                            password_confirmation: "user's password",
                                            admin: true }

    #  =======  HERE AS WELL =======
    assert_not @other_user.reload.admin?
  end
```

Comment: Hi Uzbekjon, thank you for your reply. But how do I do this? Do I just literally type in the password and the value "1" for the admin?

Comment: According to your test's name, you're testing that the user's "adminess" can not be edited from the web. So, give the `@other_user`s password and set `admin` field to true. `reload` the model and check the user is not "admin". I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanx. I ended up deleting the test form my master branch. The optional exercises gave me trouble before when I was following the tutorial, I suppose it's better to do them on a separate branch that you just don't merge...